# Pywikibot Error "Warning: Token not found on Example:de. You will not be able to edit any page"

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I tried to install Pywikibot. So far so good, the bot is able to log in, apparently access `api.php`, but when I want to run a script it says:

> Warning: Token not found on Example:de. You will not be able to edit any page

I tried to search on the web, but either I am not looking well enough or there just isn't anybody with my problem.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly did you try?

Comment: Well I am working on a way to bulk insert pages into the Wiki. There is already auto generated data and I want to find a way to "auto import". I installed the Pywikibot with this manual:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pywikibot/Use_on_non-WMF_wikis
And ran the login.py script to log the bot in. Now there already exists a script (pagefromfile.py) that does what I want. However I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: What version of MediaWiki and PWB are you using?

Comment: MediaWiki  1.20.4
PHP  5.4.11 (apache2handler)
MySQL  5.5.27

PWB Version is: 
nightly:pywikipedia 2013-04-28T17:04:21.6407030Z 11483

Comment: Im having the same problem, i believe this is some sort of permissions error but the documentation on errors is very poor. I can only suggest talking to whoever manages the wiki, they might have access to some options you dont. Like changing permissions on your account

Comment: Hah! Now it happened to me. In my case it's HTTPS which requires this patch: https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot-compat/commit/6addd6f70a386fd131acbe5c2d0b47f21a0cd68f
http://sourceforge.net/p/pywikipediabot/bugs/1662/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when server name was change. So, check hostname in your family file. However, I'm not sure it is your case because you was able to login. But may be it will help someone with similar warning message.